# Using - replace and pattern matching with XML tags Powershell

Tags: regex, xml, string, pattern-matching, powershell-3.0

I am trying to replace the contents of a string which contains xml tags as follows

I want to replace the entirety of the below statement, where ABCDEF could be any random value

```
<originalFileName>ABCDEF</originalFileName>
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This could help you:
**EDITED** (this new one will also accept non-characters between your tags and I have scaped the / symbol which can give some errors if not):

```
(<originalFileName>.*<\/originalFileName>)
```

Check it [here](https://www.regex101.com/r/iV4yL6/1).

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

You can try this for your purpose:

```
(<originalFileName>[\w]*</originalFileName>)
```

## Not recommended

However, note that it is not recommended.

Regular expressions are a tool that is insufficient to understand the constructs employed by XML/HTML/XHTML. XML/HTML/XHTML is not a regular language and hence cannot be parsed by regular expressions. Regex queries are not equipped to break down XML/HTML/XHTML into its meaningful parts. Even enhanced irregular regular expressions as used by Perl are not up to the task of parsing XML/HTML/XHTML.XML/HTML/XHTML is a language of sufficient complexity that it cannot be parsed by regular expressions.

*Further details : [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)*